# Convert HTML to plain text in JS without browser environment

Tags: javascript, regex, couchdb

I have a CouchDB view map function that generates an abstract of a stored HTML document (first `x` characters of text). Unfortunately I have no browser environment to convert HTML to plain text.

Currently I use this multi-stage regexp

```
html.replace(/<style([\s\S]*?)<\/style>/gi, ' ')
    .replace(/<script([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gi, ' ')
    .replace(/(<(?:.|\n)*?>)/gm, ' ')
    .replace(/\s+/gm, ' ');
```

while it's a very good filter, it's obviously not a perfect one and some leftovers slip through sometimes. Is there a better way to convert to plain text without a browser environment?

Comment: it may come down to using regex as you have listed for the bulk of replaces and then using a specified list replaces, such as :active; to complete the cleanse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29706729/3338098

preserves new-lines and strips html tags

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Converter HTML to plain text like Gmail:

```
html = html.replace(/<style([\s\S]*?)<\/style>/gi, '');
html = html.replace(/<script([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gi, '');
html = html.replace(/<\/div>/ig, '\n');
html = html.replace(/<\/li>/ig, '\n');
html = html.replace(/<li>/ig, '  *  ');
html = html.replace(/<\/ul>/ig, '\n');
html = html.replace(/<\/p>/ig, '\n');
html = html.replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, "\n");
html = html.replace(/<[^>]+>/ig, '');
```

If you can use `jQuery` :

```
var html = jQuery('<div>').html(html).text();
```

Comment: The DOM conversion is problematic the way you do it. This will load all links in the HTML snippet, if the html is not sanitized. This should be done via a document fragment that's not attached to the DOM.

Comment: doesn't add a `\n` in `TEXT1<div>TEXT2</div>`, i.e. it returns `TEXT1TEXT2\n`

Comment: +1 for good answer. but i want to also replace more than one new line character to one in above code. please help

Comment: `var html = jQuery(html).text();` is more simple.

Comment: The replace method works for me. The versions using jQuery html(...) or document.createElement(...) all seem to load images and scripts that may be included in the content, which is a waste of time and potential security risk (I use this function to display sample content from user input)

Comment: I think this answer misses quoting with `>` character

Comment: it should also handle links (href from <a> tags)

Comment: Doesn't this miss comment tags?

Answer (score 41):

This simple regular expression works:

```
text.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
```

It removes all anchors.

Entities, like `&lt;` does not contains <, so there is no issue with this regex.

Comment: there are also entities to take care of

Comment: worked! but its a challenge to parse those html texts in which user has placed a word inside '<>'.

Comment: Works for me for formatted HTML error messages from PHP running in Ajax.

Answer (score 12):

With TextVersionJS (https://github.com/EDMdesigner/textversionjs) you can convert your HTML to plain text. It's pure javascript (with tons of RegExps) so you can use it in the browser and in node.js as well.

In node.js it looks like:

```
var createTextVersion = require("textversionjs");
var yourHtml = "<h1>Your HTML</h1><ul><li>goes</li><li>here.</li></ul>";

var textVersion = createTextVersion(yourHtml);
```

(I copied the example from the page, you will have to npm install the module first.)

Comment: Note: it converts links to markup, so it's not quite "plain" text. Still helpful.

Comment: It also passes HTML entities right through: `&lt;` should be translated to `<` but instead is left as `&lt;`.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this way. `textContent` with `innerText` neither of them compatible with all browsers:

```
var temp = document.createElement("div");
temp.innerHTML = html;
return temp.textContent || temp.innerText || "";
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question "without browser environment".

Answer (score 4):

Updated @EpokK answer for html to **email text version** use-case

```js
const htmltoText = (html: string) => {
  let text = html;
  text = text.replace(/\n/gi, "");
  text = text.replace(/<style([\s\S]*?)<\/style>/gi, "");
  text = text.replace(/<script([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gi, "");
  text = text.replace(/<a.*?href="(.*?)[\?\"].*?>(.*?)<\/a.*?>/gi, " $2 $1 ");
  text = text.replace(/<\/div>/gi, "\n\n");
  text = text.replace(/<\/li>/gi, "\n");
  text = text.replace(/<li.*?>/gi, "  *  ");
  text = text.replace(/<\/ul>/gi, "\n\n");
  text = text.replace(/<\/p>/gi, "\n\n");
  text = text.replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, "\n");
  text = text.replace(/<[^>]+>/gi, "");
  text = text.replace(/^\s*/gim, "");
  text = text.replace(/ ,/gi, ",");
  text = text.replace(/ +/gi, " ");
  text = text.replace(/\n+/gi, "\n\n");
  return text;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something accurate and can use npm packages, I would use [html-to-text](https://github.com/html-to-text/node-html-to-text).

From the README:

```
const { htmlToText } = require('html-to-text');

const html = '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
const text = htmlToText(html, {
  wordwrap: 130
});
console.log(text); // Hello World
```

FYI, I found this on npm trends; [html-to-text](https://github.com/html-to-text/node-html-to-text) seemed like the best option for my use case but you can check out others [here](https://www.npmtrends.com/html-to-text-vs-unfluff-vs-html2plaintext-vs-textract-vs-textversionjs).

Answer (score -3):

It's pretty simple, you can also implement a "toText" prototype:

```
String.prototype.toText = function(){
    return $(html).text();
};

//Let's test it out!
var html = "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">link</a>&nbsp;<br /><b>TEXT</b>";
var text = html.toText();
console.log("Text: " + text); //Result will be "link TEXT"
```

Comment: really don't see how this answer is relevant.