# Extract text from HTML while preserving block-level element newlines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, strip

## Background

Most [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/822452/59087) about extracting text from HTML (i.e., [stripping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/59087) the tags) use:

```
jQuery( htmlString ).text();
```

While this abstracts browser inconsistencies (such as `innerText` vs. `textContent`), the function call also ignores the semantic meaning of block-level elements (such as `li`).

## Problem

Preserving newlines of block-level elements (i.e., the semantic intent) across various browsers entails no small effort, as [Mike Wilcox describes](http://clubajax.org/plain-text-vs-innertext-vs-textcontent/).

A seemingly simpler solution would be to emulate pasting HTML content into a `<textarea>`, which strips HTML while preserving block-level element newlines. However, JavaScript-based inserts do not trigger the same HTML-to-text routines that browsers employ when users paste content into a `<textarea>`.

I also tried integrating Mike Wilcox's [JavaScript code](http://clubajax.org/files/lang/plain-text.js). The code works in Chromium, but not in Firefox.

## Question

What is the simplest cross-browser way to extract text from HTML while preserving semantic newlines for [block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements) using jQuery (or [vanilla JavaScript](http://vanilla-js.com/))?

## Example

Consider:

1. Select and copy this entire question.
2. Open the [textarea example page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#HTML_Content).
3. Paste the content into the textarea.

The textarea preserves the newlines for ordered lists, headings, preformatted text, and so forth. That is the result I would like to achieve.

To further clarify, given any HTML content, such as:

```
   <h1>Header</h1>
   <p>Paragraph</p>
   <ul>
     <li>First</li>
     <li>Second</li>
   </ul>
   <dl>
     <dt>Term</dt>
       <dd>Definition</dd>
   </dl>
   <div>Div with <span>span</span>.<br />After the <a href="...">break</a>.</div>
```

How would you produce:

```
  Header
  Paragraph

    First
    Second

  Term
    Definition

  Div with span.
  After the break.
```

Note: Neither indentation nor non-normalized whitespace are relevant.

Comment: It sounds like an interesting problem. I expect an approach that iterates over elements and nodes, inserting a new line wherever it enters or leaves an element with a block computed style (but not doubling–up if there's no intervening text node) or an element that causes a new line (maybe BR, HR, TR). Dealing with tables is another issue.

Comment: I got something working, but it relies on the HTML format: http://jsfiddle.net/jLpCT/. If you really want to get indented text based on block level events, you would have to inspect every element and make a decision based on whether the element is block level or not (and maybe also treat different block level elements differently). As you can see, I posted an answer but deleted it since I wasn't sure if that's the direction you want to go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider:

```
/**
 * Returns the style for a node.
 *
 * @param n The node to check.
 * @param p The property to retrieve (usually 'display').
 * @link http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html
 */
this.getStyle = function( n, p ) {
  return n.currentStyle ?
    n.currentStyle[p] :
    document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(n, null).getPropertyValue(p);
}

/**
 * Converts HTML to text, preserving semantic newlines for block-level
 * elements.
 *
 * @param node - The HTML node to perform text extraction.
 */
this.toText = function( node ) {
  var result = '';

  if( node.nodeType == document.TEXT_NODE ) {
    // Replace repeated spaces, newlines, and tabs with a single space.
    result = node.nodeValue.replace( /\s+/g, ' ' );
  }
  else {
    for( var i = 0, j = node.childNodes.length; i < j; i++ ) {
      result += _this.toText( node.childNodes[i] );
    }

    var d = _this.getStyle( node, 'display' );

    if( d.match( /^block/ ) || d.match( /list/ ) || d.match( /row/ ) ||
        node.tagName == 'BR' || node.tagName == 'HR' ) {
      result += '\n';
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3mzrV/2/

That is to say, with an exception or two, iterate through each node and print its contents, letting the browser's computed style tell you when to insert newlines.

Comment: `getStyle` always returns `''` so I'll assume this means the "`node`" has to be active in the DOM for this to work?

Comment: changed to support `TEXT1<div>TEXT2</div>`=>`TEXT1\nTEXT2` http://stackoverflow.com/a/29706729/3338098

Comment: The fiddle uses a simplified version of the code shown in the answer. I ended up using the fiddle version, with superfluous newlines removed by running the result through `.replace(/\n{3,}/g,'\n\n')`.

Comment: Created this fork (http://jsfiddle.net/14rpmyn3/2/) to use `<p>` wrapped blocks instead of `\n`, which would be more appropriate for insertion into the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be (nearly) doing what you want:

```
function getText($node) {
    return $node.contents().map(function () {
        if (this.nodeName === 'BR') {
            return '\n';
        } else if (this.nodeType === 3) {
            return this.nodeValue;
        } else {
            return getText($(this));
        }
    }).get().join('');
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jLpCT/)

It just recursively concatenates the values of all text nodes and replaces `<br>` elements with line breaks.

But there is no semantics in this, it **completely** relies the original HTML formatting (the leading and trailing white spaces seem to come from how jsFiddle embeds the HTML, but you can easily trim those). For example, notice how it indents the definition term.

If you really want to do this on a semantic level, you need a list of block level elements, recursively iterate over the elements and indent them accordingly. You treat different block elements differently with respect to indentation and line breaks around them. This should not be too difficult.

Answer (score 2):

based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/20384452/3338098
and fixed to support `TEXT1<div>TEXT2</div>`=>`TEXT1\nTEXT2` and allow non-DOM nodes

```
/**
 * Returns the style for a node.
 *
 * @param n The node to check.
 * @param p The property to retrieve (usually 'display').
 * @link http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html
 */
function getNodeStyle( n, p ) {
  return n.currentStyle ?
    n.currentStyle[p] :
    document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(n, null).getPropertyValue(p);
}

//IF THE NODE IS NOT ACTUALLY IN THE DOM then this won't take into account <div style="display: inline;">text</div>
//however for simple things like `contenteditable` this is sufficient, however for arbitrary html this will not work
function isNodeBlock(node) {
  if (node.nodeType == document.TEXT_NODE) {return false;}
  var d = getNodeStyle( node, 'display' );//this is irrelevant if the node isn't currently in the current DOM.
  if (d.match( /^block/ ) || d.match( /list/ ) || d.match( /row/ ) ||
      node.tagName == 'BR' || node.tagName == 'HR' ||
      node.tagName == 'DIV' // div,p,... add as needed to support non-DOM nodes
     ) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

/**
 * Converts HTML to text, preserving semantic newlines for block-level
 * elements.
 *
 * @param node - The HTML node to perform text extraction.
 */
function htmlToText( htmlOrNode, isNode ) {
  var node = htmlOrNode;
  if (!isNode) {node = jQuery("<span>"+htmlOrNode+"</span>")[0];}
  //TODO: inject "unsafe" HTML into current DOM while guaranteeing that it won't
  //      change the visible DOM so that `isNodeBlock` will work reliably
  var result = '';
  if( node.nodeType == document.TEXT_NODE ) {
    // Replace repeated spaces, newlines, and tabs with a single space.
    result = node.nodeValue.replace( /\s+/g, ' ' );
  } else {
    for( var i = 0, j = node.childNodes.length; i < j; i++ ) {
      result += htmlToText( node.childNodes[i], true );
      if (i < j-1) {
        if (isNodeBlock(node.childNodes[i])) {
          result += '\n';
        } else if (isNodeBlock(node.childNodes[i+1]) &&
                   node.childNodes[i+1].tagName != 'BR' &&
                   node.childNodes[i+1].tagName != 'HR') {
          result += '\n';
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

the main change was

```
      if (i < j-1) {
        if (isNodeBlock(node.childNodes[i])) {
          result += '\n';
        } else if (isNodeBlock(node.childNodes[i+1]) &&
                   node.childNodes[i+1].tagName != 'BR' &&
                   node.childNodes[i+1].tagName != 'HR') {
          result += '\n';
        }
      }
```

to check neighboring blocks to determine the appropriateness of adding a newline.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest a little edit from the code of svidgen:

```js
function getText(n, isInnerNode) {
  var rv = '';
  if (n.nodeType == 3) {
      rv = n.nodeValue;
  } else {
      var partial = "";
      var d = getComputedStyle(n).getPropertyValue('display');
      if (isInnerNode && d.match(/^block/) || d.match(/list/) || n.tagName == 'BR') {
          partial += "\n";
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < n.childNodes.length; i++) {
          partial += getText(n.childNodes[i], true);
      }
      rv = partial;
  }
  return rv;
 };
```

I just added the line break before the for loop, in this way we have a newline before the block, and also a variable to avoid the newline for the root element.

The code should be invocated:

```js
getText(document.getElementById("divElement"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.innerText`
This not return extra nodes added from contenteditable elements.
If you use `element.innerHTML` the text will contain additional markup, but innerText will return what you see on the element's contents.

```
<div id="txt" contenteditable="true"></div>

<script>
  var txt=document.getElementById("txt");
  var withMarkup=txt.innerHTML;
  var textOnly=txt.innerText;
  console.log(withMarkup);
  console.log(textOnly);
</script>
```