# rendering encoded html tags as string

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, xss

In our use case ' hello ' is a valid description field's value.
Our back-end encodes this content. When we fetch it, we get-

```
&lt;h1&gt; hello &lt;/hi&gt;
```

but, we would like to present ' hello ' as a *string* and not html
We use react if it makes any difference
1. Should our backend save the original string or should it keep encoding?
2. How can we render our decoded tags as simple text?

Comment: How about doing the conversion on the client side? http://stackoverflow.com/a/38612671/58129